# How to login to website and get json data in Android Listview?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, authentication

I have webpage with secured php login page and if i enter my login details its redirecting to data.json file.

But if you are not authenticated, t shows nothing?!

Can anyone show me code or example how to make authentication in android to get data from server? I already tried to make get_data.php what can enter to mysql and convert it to json, but how i can secure it and after that enter and get it in android app?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

To make the login you can use Jsoup library https://jsoup.org/

```
 final String USER_AGENT = "\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT\" +\n" +
     "\" 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.120 Safari/535.2\"";
    String loginFormUrl = "https://page.com/login";
    String loginActionUrl = "https://page.com/json";
    String username = "email@gmail.com";
    String password = "XXXX";

 HashMap<String, String> cookies = new HashMap<>();  
 HashMap<String, String> formData = new HashMap<>();  


 Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect(loginFormUrl).method(Connection.Method.GET).userAgent(USER_AGENT).execute();  
 Document loginDoc = loginForm.parse(); // this is the document that contains response 

 cookies.putAll(loginForm.cookies()); // save the cookies, this will be passed on to next request  

 formData.put("commit", "Sign in");  
 formData.put("utf8", "e2 9c 93");  
 formData.put("login", username);  
 formData.put("password", password);  
 formData.put("authenticity_token", authToken);  

 Connection.Response homePage = Jsoup.connect(loginActionUrl)  
         .cookies(cookies)  
         .data(formData)  
         .method(Connection.Method.POST)  
         .userAgent(USER_AGENT)  
         .execute();  

System.out.println(homePage.parse().html());  //The json response use this to iterate and draw
```